# Android: Define programmatically RelativeLayout inside ViewFlipper

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, viewflipper

Based on this [article](http://javatechig.com/android/android-viewflipper-example), I've tried to build a ViewFlipper with multiple RelativeLayouts.

When proceeding as written in article (only change the height), I got (as expected) a ViewFlipper normally displayed :

[image: ViewFlipper with xml]

My xml :

```
 <ViewFlipper
      android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp" >

      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:adjustViewBounds="true"
              android:scaleType="centerCrop"
              android:src="@drawable/img1" />

          <TextView
              style="@style/ImageTitle"
              android:text="Test test" />
      </RelativeLayout>
  </ViewFlipper>
```

Style:

```
<style name="ImageTitle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">#99000000</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
</style>
```

Then I've tried do generate RelativeLayout programmatically with the code below :

```
public void generateViewForFlipper(String url, int id, String text){

    //new RelativeLayout
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    //Params for the RelaviteLayout
     final ViewFlipper.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams = new ViewFlipper.LayoutParams(
             ViewFlipper.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewFlipper.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

     //ImageView
     ImageView imageView = new ImageView (this);
     imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1));
     imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
     imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

     // Params for the ImageView
     final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );

     //Application title
     TextView textView = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tvtemplate, null);
     textView.setText(text);


    // Params for application title
     final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50);


     mViewFlipper.addView(relativeLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);

     relativeLayout.addView(imageView,imageParams);
     relativeLayout.addView(textView,textParams);

}
```

tvtemplate.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/ImageTitle" />
```

Result screen :

[image: defined grammatically]

As you can see, text is not aligned to the bottom, not "match_parent", and picture is not cropped..

Thank you

Comment: Try to change ViewFlipper height to match_parent instead of fix (200dp).

Comment: Thank you. As you can see on the second picture, ViewFLipper size is correct( picture height equals 200dp )

Comment: Now try replace this properties  android:scaleType="centerCrop" to android:scaleType="centerInside" in xml.

Comment: I tried to set it to "centerInside" but no effect.